# UISearchbar Covered by parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

[image]

Table will add an option cell under the cell which's right button has been pressed. then table auto scroll and show whole header, but the invisible part of searchbar will cover by parent view. it will show all right immediately if scroll the table a little.  have some way to fix it? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Add[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2thM.jpg):

```
[currentTableView beginUpdates];

NSMutableArray *addCellIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:optionCellIndexPath, nil];

[currentTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addCellIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[currentTableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: can you please put some code for your tableview

Comment: try this `[_aTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];` in the method u are making the tableview to scroll automatically

Comment: @Shan , I cannot do this , the tableview will scroll to the Offset Point(0, 0). How can i fix this without scroll the tableview?

Comment: you are doing auto scroll, when cell's rite button clicked rite, at that time u set to offset to zero

Comment: @Shan do u mean like this?

[currentTableView beginUpdates];

NSMutableArray *addCellIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:optionCellIndexPath, nil];

[currentTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:addCellIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[currentTableView endUpdates];

[currentTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];

Comment: no in this are adding new cells, but in the action method of rite button , where u are making table view to scroll to top

Comment: @Shan, I do not making table view to scroll,  when table content less than a page, it auto scroll an show whole header, i think it uitableview features?

Comment: ok try it in there only not sure put it before `[currentTableView beginUpdates];`  don't put it in between begin and end  updates

Comment: I tried it but useless, do u know why the searchbar cover by parent view ?

Comment: check the frame of tableview, where exactly its y position lies, by setting the content offset to zero point means it will show whole tableview from the top